# iOS UIwebview cookies are not being set for subsequent requests

Tags: ios, cordova, cookies, uiwebview, nsmutableurlrequest

We are using a modified inAppbrowser cordova plugin in our hybrid mobile application. While loading the first request in my UIWebview, I am setting couple of cookies. Here is my code

```
 NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TOKEN_1=%@; TOKEN_2=%@;", @"VALUE_1", @"VALUE_2"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];

[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

We are using the above token cookies to SSO into other applications. It is working fine.

Once I initiate the above request, it goes through multiple url redirections. In each request, server tries to set some extra cookies in the response. Below is the response of the above request.

```
Location: /my.policy
Set-Cookie: Session_1=5f1dddd; domain=bhh.com;path=/;secure
Set-Cookie: session_2=0813d65bcbbf631a4f3d482f5f19560d; domain=bhh.com;path=/;secure
```

as per the above response from server, next request should go to /my.policy with the above cookies ( Session_1 , session_2). When I look at the charles proxy, The next request also contains only the tokens that I set at the beginning ( TOKEN_1, TOKEN_2 ). The cookies that the server sent is not being set to next requests. I kept some logs in **shouldStartLoadWithRequest** delegate method to read cookies from **sharedHTTPCookieStorage**. I could see the server cookies are present in cookiestorage but they are not passed along with request.

If I remove the cookie setting of first request (removed TOKEN_1 and TOKEN_2 ), then server cookies are being sent for the subsequent requests.

I tried the following ways to solve my but none of them worked.

Tried to set cookies to request in **shouldStartLoadWithRequest** delegate method by reading from cookie storage.

Tried setting cookie policy

```
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: Nope .. it is still waiting in my backlog :)